# Boost error: not found boost_date_time-vc80-mt-1_41.dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, boost, boost-date-time

I need to run examples of software that uses boost libraries for VS2008,
but the following error occurs: this application can not be started because it was not found `boost_date_time-vc80-mt-1_41.dll`

I have set the `PATH` variable:

```
set PATH=C:\opt\boost-1_41_0\lib;
```

What's actually causing this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Where is "boost_date_time-vc80-mt-1_41.dll" file located?

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this link to work with Boost libraries with VS 2008:
http://smolsky.net/index.php/2009/12/08/building-boost

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11597/Building-Boost-libraries-for-Visual-Studio

Hope so it will resolve your problem.

Comment: So, I had downloaded the boost libraries for VS2008, so do not understand the error.

Comment: @David: After downloading the boost libraries you have to install it. Follow the link from code project: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11597/Building-Boost-libraries-for-Visual-Studio

Comment: I did this. I used the command line: bjam toolset=msvc-9.0 --build-type=complete stage

I used this site: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/more/getting_started/windows.html#or-build-binaries-from-source